# How to group multiple AND/OR statements in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to filter out NHT out of my BigQuery with some criterion I have found in my Dataset from Google Analytics. For my example I want these two sets of criterion filtered out:

```
networkLocation REGEXP_Contains (r"^(ovh \(nwk\)|hostwinds llc.|bhost inc|prisma networks llc|psychz networks|buyvm services|private customer|secure dragon llc.|vmpanel|netaction telecom srl-d|hostigation|frontlayer technologies inc.|digital energy technologies limited|owned-networks|rica web services|netaction telecom srl-d|hurricane electric inc.|private customer - host.howpick.com|ssdvirt|sway broadband|detect network|gorillaservers inc.|micfo llc.|    netaction telecom srl|egihosting|zenlayer inc|intercom online inc.|gs1 argentine|ovh hosting inc.|vps cheap inc.|limeip networks|blackhost ltd.|amazon.com inc.)$")

AND

device.browserVersion REGEXP_Contains(r"^(41.0|55.0)$")

OR

networkLocation REGEXP_Contains ("^(hpro group ltd)$")

AND

device.browserVersion REGEXP_Contains("45.0")
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT
  channelGrouping,
  date,
  h.page.pagePath AS Page,
  SUM(totals.timeOnSite) AS Session_Duration,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
  AVG(totals.timeonSite/totals.visits) AS Avg_Time_per_Session,
  SUM(totals.bounces) AS Bounce,
  (SUM(totals.bounces)/SUM(totals.visits)) AS Bounce_rate,
  geoNetwork.networkLocation,
  device.browserVersion,
  device.browser
FROM
  `93868086.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) as h
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
  date,
  channelGrouping,
  geoNetwork.networkLocation,
  device.browserVersion,
  device.browser,
  h.page.pagePath
```

I need a HAVING NOT Clause however I am not sure how to group the set of statements I need to filter out my criterion. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your expressions for criterion are correct  - below should be a way

```
HAVING NOT (
  (
  REGEXP_CONTAINS (networkLocation, r"^(ovh \(nwk\)|hostwinds llc.|bhost inc|prisma networks llc|psychz networks|buyvm services|private customer|secure dragon llc.|vmpanel|netaction telecom srl-d|hostigation|frontlayer technologies inc.|digital energy technologies limited|owned-networks|rica web services|netaction telecom srl-d|hurricane electric inc.|private customer - host.howpick.com|ssdvirt|sway broadband|detect network|gorillaservers inc.|micfo llc.|    netaction telecom srl|egihosting|zenlayer inc|intercom online inc.|gs1 argentine|ovh hosting inc.|vps cheap inc.|limeip networks|blackhost ltd.|amazon.com inc.)$")
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(device.browserVersion, r"^(41.0|55.0)$")
  ) OR (
  REGEXP_CONTAINS (networkLocation, r"^(hpro group ltd)$")
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(device.browserVersion, r"45.0")
  )
)
```

Comment: If I were to add 2 more sets of criterion on top of the ones I presented would be as simple as adding another OR statement after the last paranthesis and adding the other statements in?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help! I like the way you format your parenthesis it makes it alot easier to keep track of instead of counting from both sides of the statement haha.

Comment: sure. I believe that proper formatting is at least 50% success especially with complex and wordy queries